# Meu código não executa!

Tags: javascript, css3

Eu to aprendendo a mexer no JS e estou fazendo um joguinho.

Quero saber o que há de errado com ele, pois coloquei o código exatamente igual a video-aula que eu assisto, mas não roda de jeito algum.

Era para criar uma tela no centro da página, mas não aparece nada.
Segue abaixo o código:

```js
var canvas, ctx, LARGURA, ALTURA, frame = 0

function main() {
  ALTURA = window.innerHeight
  LARGURA = window.innerWidth

  if (LARGURA >= 500) {
    ALTURA = 600
    LARGURA = 600
  }


  canvas = document.createElement("canvas")
  canvas.width = LARGURA
  canvas.height = ALTURA


  canvas.style.border = "1px solid #000"
}
```

```css
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <title>Página Inicial</title>

</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <nav></nav>
  </header>
  <div></div>
  <article>
    <section>


    </section>
  </article>

  <aside></aside>

  <div></div>

  <footer></footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Leia: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084/como-devemos-formatar-perguntas-e-respostas/1297#1297

Comment: Tem que chamar o método `main()` você só o declarou mas não fez o uso dele.

Comment: Como faço para chama-lo no html?

Comment: Só evocar dentro do script como uma função normal assim `main()` ou no html o colocar em um manipulador de eventos `onclick="main()"`. PS: No comentário anterior eu chamei de método, mas é apenas uma função.

Comment: Coloquei o main() no final do script, mas ainda assim não aparece nada...

Comment: Está faltando algumas coisas no seu código. Estou dando uma olhada você precisa anexa o elemento criado em `canvas = document.createElement("canvas")` a página assim `document.body.appendChild(canvas);` . Documentaçao do `appendChild`: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild

Comment: canvas = document.createElement("canvas")
 document.body.appendChild(canvas) // aparece error no console " script.js:15 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null "

Comment: Dá uma olhada na resposta que coloquei está lá está comentado. Clique em Executar para ver o resultado. No lado superior direito da visualização tem o botão Página Toda.

Comment: Ta rodando aqui, mas o meu não roda...aparece a msg de erro no console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como disse nos comentários está faltando algumas coisas no seu código.

Primeiro precisa evocar a função `main()`, ela foi declarada mas não foi usada.

Você precisa também anexar o elemento criado na linha

```
canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
```

a sua página usando o método [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild). Veja no exemplo:

```js
var canvas, ctx, LARGURA, ALTURA, frame = 0

function main() {
  ALTURA = window.innerHeight
  LARGURA = window.innerWidth

  if (LARGURA >= 500) {
    //Diminuí largura e altura para facilitar a visualização
    ALTURA = 300 
    LARGURA = 300
  }


  canvas = document.createElement("canvas")
  canvas.width = LARGURA
  canvas.height = ALTURA


  canvas.style.border = "1px solid #000"

  //Faltou em seu código adicionar o canvas ao corpo do documento
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);

}

main(); //Faltou em seu código evocar o método main()
```

```css
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <title>Página Inicial</title>

</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <nav></nav>
  </header>
  <div></div>
  <article>
    <section>


    </section>
  </article>

  <aside></aside>

  <div></div>

  <footer></footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: O código não ta pegando no meu, o console diz : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
    at main " Eu fiz as alterações que você comentou

Comment: Nesse console aqui da página? Cliquei em executar e funcionou corretamente Veja a imagem: https://imgur.com/HeZh9q9

Comment: Não daqui, o daqui funcionou, mas no meu. Eu executo o meu na web do VS code e o console aparece esse erro.

Comment: Comenta com um print, deve ser erro de digitação.

Comment: Você salvou o documento depois que modificou? Alguns linters de JS só analisam a versão salva do arquivo.

Comment: Não consigo compartilhar o print que eu tirei, o comentário não coloca a foto. Tem algum instagram ou outro local que eu possa enviar

Comment: Usa esse site `https://imgur.com/` é o oficial da página.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/r5lzuc7

Comment: **Provavelmente** você está carregando o seu arquivo JS como se fosse um módulo a parte https://imgur.com/gQaRzyw, Preciso ver a tag `<script>` do HTML acredito que seja lá o erro. Mas a maneira mais simples de resolver é deixar esse código na própria página.

Comment: Escrevi esse código, no VS code tem que estar assim: https://repl.it/@RonaldoVasques/ComoDeveriaEstarNoVSCode

Comment: Olha o reply, meu código na íntegra. https://repl.it/repls/LegitimateHorribleFile

Comment: É porque está no `<head>` o DOM ainda não foi carregado tem que mover para o final do arquivo ou colocar para funcionar no evento `load`. Do jeito que está fazendo é melhor solução é migrar a tag `<script>` para o final da página.

Comment: Olha o seu script modificado: https://repl.it/@RonaldoVasques/LegitimateHorribleFile

Comment: Meu Deus, era isso kkkk! Valeu mano...